# Laravel 5 codeception functional testing, wait for full page load

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, codeception

I am trying to write a functional test using codeception for Laravel 5. Fails to validate elements loaded by JS. How do I wait for all JS to be run and the page to be fully loaded. It this achievable?

Comment: `$I->waitForElement('#my-element', 30); // timeout in secs`

Comment: Be careful with this approach. While it may work for limited circumstances, it'll soon become cumbersome and your tests will take a long time to run.

Comment: @BenSwinburne waitForElement is not available for functional testing. Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Selenium for this. Laravel has Selenium support out of the box (though you'll still need to download the Selenium standalone server and have Java installed)